# Concourse CI tsa.connection.forward-worker.register.failed-to-fetch-containers

Tags: concourse

I am using concourse 2.5.0 migrated to environment options instead of flags to binary.
And getting error

```
"source":"tsa","message":"tsa.connection.forward-worker.register.failed-to-fetch-containers","log_level":2,"data":{"error":"invalid character '\u003c' looking for beginning of value","remote":"127.0.0.1:40200"
```

worker config

```
export CONCOURSE_NAME=vagrantci
export CONCOURSE_WORK_DIR=/opt/concourseci/worker
export CONCOURSE_BIND_PORT=8080
export CONCOURSE_TSA_HOST=vagrantci
export CONCOURSE_TSA_PORT=2222
export CONCOURSE_TSA_PUBLIC_KEY=/opt/concourseci/.ssh/tsa.pub
export CONCOURSE_TSA_WORKER_PRIVATE_KEY=/opt/concourseci/.ssh/worker
```

web config

```
export CONCOURSE_BIND_IP=0.0.0.0
export CONCOURSE_BIND_PORT=8080
export CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL=http://192.168.50.150:8080
export CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_DATA_SOURCE=postgres://user:pass@127.0.0.1/concourse?sslmode=disable
export CONCOURSE_SESSION_SIGNING_KEY=/opt/concourseci/.ssh/session_signing
export CONCOURSE_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=user
export CONCOURSE_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=pass
export CONCOURSE_TSA_BIND_IP=0.0.0.0
export CONCOURSE_TSA_BIND_PORT=2222
export CONCOURSE_TSA_HOST_KEY=/opt/concourseci/.ssh/tsa
export CONCOURSE_TSA_AUTHORIZED_KEYS=/opt/concourseci/.ssh/tsa_authorization
```

Any idea what is wrong ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

My bad, worker should not have CONCOURSE_BIND_PORT=8080